What is correct option regarding $ax+b,x+c$ orthogonal to each other...
Let $\mathbb{R}$ be a field of real numbers and V is the vectorspace of $P(\mathbb{R})$ of degree almost one. consider the bilinear form
$$<>: V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$$ such that $$<f,g>=\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) dx$$
which of the following is true
(1) $\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}-\{ 0\}, \exists c$ such that $ax+b,x+c\in V $ are orthogonal to each other.
(2)$\forall b\in \mathbb{R}-\{ 0\}$, there are infinitely many $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x+b,x+c\in V$ are orthogonal to each other.
(3) $\forall c\in \mathbb{R^+}$ there exists infinitely many $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ax+b,x+c\in V$ are orthogonal to ecah other.
(4)$\forall b\neq 0$ there exists infintely $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that vectors $b,x+c$ are orthogonal to each other.
I know by orthogonal they mean $<f,g>=\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx=0$.
So for option 1, $f(x)=ax+b$ and $g(x)=x+c$ we have $f(x)g(x)=ax^2+(ac+b)x+bc$ and hence the integral from 0 to 1 will be $\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx=\frac{a^3}{3}+\frac{ac+b}{2}+bc$.
So we want $\frac{a^3}{3}+\frac{ac+b}{2}+bc=0$ , So if I consider option 1, it will be correct since if I chose any two non zero $a,b$ then we can get $c$ by solving $\frac{a^3}{3}+\frac{ac+b}{2}+bc=0$. i.e. for all a,b we are getting c such that $ax+b,x+c\in V $ are orthogonal to each other.
For option 2, since $a=1$ now, $\int_0^1f(x)g(x)=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{c+b}{2}+bc$ so if we take any $c$ positive then by solving $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{c+b}{2}+bc=0$ we can get a value for $c$ but that $c$ will be unique value for each $b$ chosen. So option 2 must be incorrect
For option 3, if we choose a particular $c$ and fix a value for $a$ then we will get unique value for $b$, so by choosing infinite values for $a$ we can get corresponding values of $b$. So we get say $\forall c\in \mathbb{R^+}$ there exists infinitely many $a,b$ such that $ax+b,x+c\in V$ are orthogonal to each other. so option 3 should be correct.
Now for option 4, $a=0$ so we get the integral value as $\frac{b}{2}+bc=0$. so here for each positive $c$ we will get unique $b$ not infinitely many. so option 4 is also incorrect..
Am I correct....But in the solution they have given only option 3 is correct where I am wrong please reply...
Thanks in advance...

In option 1, actually solve it and find $c$.  Do you always get an answer ?
